# Gunicorn file for Django project gunicorn.service keep getting Permission denied

Tags: django, service, centos, gunicorn, permission-denied

Hello I am currently practicing Linux and Django project using Gunicorn and Nginx on CentOS.
I'm testing my server on **AWS Lightsail** and here's some info of what I'm using for this practice.

- **CS9-20230110**
- **Python 3.9**
- **Django 4.0.2**
- **Nginx 1.22.1**
- **Gunicorn 21.2.0**

The test of opening the server by opening a gunicorn socket and port 8000 with Gunicorn was successful. I had no trouble in here.
`gunicorn --bind 0:8000 mysite.wsgi:application`
`gunicorn --bind unix:/home/ec2-user/Django/venv/gunicorn.sock config.wsgi:application`
(I put sock file into my venv directory, thinking this could've be the problem (sadly it wasn't))

But when I try to start Gunicorn service on systemd. The system send permission denied message on gunicorn file.

So I set every single files UID and GID to my user account and group and set 775 authorization on most files. It didn't work at all.

I have no clue what I'm missing now. Just thinking that I made a mistake and the mess is everywhere now.  Please someone tell me what's going on here.

## **Directory Tree**

```
# /home/ec2-user/Django
Django
├── Django_Project
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── mysite
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── db.sqlite3
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   │   ├── base.py
│   │   │   ├── local.py
│   │   │   └── prod.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── nohup.out
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── templates
│       └── base.html
└── venv
    ├── bin
    │   ├── activate
    │   ├── activate.csh
    │   ├── activate.fish
    │   ├── Activate.ps1
    │   ├── django-admin
    │   ├── gunicorn
    │   ├── markdown_py
    │   ├── pip
    │   ├── pip3
    │   ├── pip3.11
    │   ├── pip3.9
    │   ├── python -> python3
    │   ├── python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
    │   ├── python3.9 -> python3
    │   ├── sqlformat
    │   └── wheel
    ├── gunicorn.sock
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    │   └── python3.9
    ├── lib64 -> lib
    ├── mysite.env
    └── pyvenv.cfg
```

## **This is the system status**

```
[root@ip-172-26-14-187 ec2-user]# systemctl status gunicorn.service
× gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-12-09 17:55:51 UTC; 1s ago
   Duration: 6ms
TriggeredBy: ○ gunicorn.socket
    Process: 55311 ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/Django/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 2 --bind unix:/home/ec2-user/Django/venv/gunicorn.sock mysite.wsgi:application (code=exited>
   Main PID: 55311 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 3ms

Dec 09 17:55:51 ip-172-26-14-187.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Dec 09 17:55:51 ip-172-26-14-187.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal systemd[55311]: gunicorn.service: Failed to locate executable /home/ec2-user/Django/venv/bin/gunicorn: Permission denied
Dec 09 17:55:51 ip-172-26-14-187.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal systemd[55311]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/ec2-user/Django/venv/bin/gunicorn: Permission denied
Dec 09 17:55:51 ip-172-26-14-187.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dec 09 17:55:51 ip-172-26-14-187.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

## **gunicorn.service file**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user

WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/Django/Django_Project
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/Django/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 2 --bind unix:/home/ec2-user/Django/venv/gunicorn.sock mysite.wsgi:a
pplication

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I write one more line like `EnvironmentFile=/home/ec2-user/Django/venv/mysite.env`.
This also comes out with `Permission denied` message.

```
gunicorn.service: Failed to load environment files: Permission denied
gunicorn.service: Failed to run 'start' task: Permission denied
gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
```

## **Permissions**

**Project and venv directory**

```
drwxrwxr-x. 8 ec2-user ec2-user 176 Dec  9 11:07 Django_Project
drwxr-xr-x. 8 ec2-user ec2-user 176 Dec  7 17:43 Django_Project_Backup
drwxrwxr-x. 5 ec2-user ec2-user 113 Dec  9 17:28 venv
```

**Django/venv**

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec  9 16:54 bin
srwxrwxrwx. 1 ec2-user ec2-user    0 Dec  9 17:23 gunicorn.sock
drwxr-xr-x. 2 ec2-user ec2-user    6 Dec  7 03:11 include
drwxr-xr-x. 3 ec2-user ec2-user   23 Dec  7 03:11 lib
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ec2-user ec2-user    3 Dec  7 03:11 lib64 -> lib
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user   44 Dec  9 15:49 mysite.env
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user   70 Dec  7 03:11 pyvenv.cfg
```

**Django/venv/bin**

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1901 Dec  7 03:12 activate
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  850 Dec  7 03:12 activate.csh
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1990 Dec  7 03:12 activate.fish
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 8834 Dec  7 03:12 Activate.ps1
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  285 Dec  7 03:21 django-admin
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  239 Dec  9 16:54 gunicorn
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  236 Dec  7 03:21 markdown_py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  243 Dec  7 03:22 pip
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  243 Dec  7 03:22 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  243 Dec  7 03:22 pip3.11
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  243 Dec  7 03:22 pip3.9
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ec2-user ec2-user    7 Dec  7 03:11 python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ec2-user ec2-user   16 Dec  7 03:11 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ec2-user ec2-user    7 Dec  7 03:11 python3.9 -> python3
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  238 Dec  7 03:17 sqlformat
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  230 Dec  7 03:20 wheel
```

**/etc/systemd/system**

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  327 Dec  9 17:42  gunicorn.service
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Dec  9 15:46  multi-user.target.wants
```

I tried to change UID and GID, set authorization to 775 in all files in Django project.
I was expecting to system to have a permission to use gunicorn file in venv/bin directory.

Comment: Downgrading gunicorn didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was SELinux.

I use `setenforce 0` command to disable the SELinux.
Now its on the systemd.